# Asp.Net асинхронность и HttpContext.Current

Tags: .net, asp.net, асинхронность, faq

Пытаюсь перевести свое приложение на асинхронные вызовы. Столкнулся с тем что внутри порожденных потоков не могу использовать HttpContext родительского процесса. Решил (решил ли?) проблему следующим образом

```
var threadContext = HttpContext.Current;

var result = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    HttpContext.Current = threadContext;
    // внутри longOperation() будет использоваться HttpContext.Current 
    return longOperation();
});
```

Вопрос

- правильно ли я делаю или есть более приемлемый, рекомендованный метод?
- конкретно использую HttpContext.Current.Session. Есть ли другой способ добраться до нее внутри порожденных процессов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно эту проблему вы решаете правильно, но сам по себе подход к асинхронности у вас неверен.

Есть два типа нагрузки:

- CPU-bound - например, долгий расчет чего-то.
- IO-bound - ожидание ответа внешнего по отношению к приложению источника.

Ваш код пытается распараллелить CPU-bound нагрузку. Это не дает никакого эффекта. А чаще всего - просто приносит вред:

- код все равно не уходит дальше `var result =`
- код все равно занимает минимум один поток - он же выполняет `longOperation`
- код все так же использует поток из пула - только отпускает текущий поток, и ждет выделения нового. а это может произойти не мгновенно.

т.е. ваш код эквивалентен

```
var result = longOperation();
```

только с тормозами.

Распараллеливать в ASP.NET имеет смысл только IO-bound нагрузку.

IO-bound нагрузка - это, например метод [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx) - он возвращает таск, который будет завершен по приходу данных от SQL. Т.е. ваше приложение в момент ожидания данных не ест проц, не делает вычислений, а просто ждет ответа. И вот именно в этом случае есть смысл написать

```
var result = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

т.к. этот `await` освободит текущий поток, и он сможет обработать другой запрос. А после прихода ответа от SQL - ваш код продолжит работу c `result` с уже подставленным `HttpContext`.

Т.е. тру способ сделать "правильную" асинхронность - это сделать полный стек `async` методов

- [`async Action`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) в контроллере
- `async SomeOperation` в сервисе
- [`async IQueryable.ToListAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx), если у вас EF.
- [`async SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx), если вы работаете с SQL напрямую.

И только тогда вы сможете получить от асинхронности профит в виде освобождения потоков и лучшей масштабируемости.

---

В десктопе есть смысл применять `async`и для выгрузки IO-bound, и для выгрузки CPU-bound кода в отдельный поток. Но только потому, что это освобождает UI-поток - и убирает блокировку UI во время долгих операций, даже если они чисто CPU-bound.

В вебе ваш код и так выполняется на потоке из Thread Pool. Выгрузка его в другой (точно такой же) поток из Thread Pool ничего не даст. Единственное, что может дать какой-то эффект - это распараллеливание - выполнение отдельных частей longOperation в несколько потоков (`Parallel.For`). Тогда общий результат будет получен быстрее.

Но такой подход дает не совсем ожидаемые результаты - вы получите прирост производительности при тестовых замерах - потому что один запрос будет выполняться, скажем, в 4 потока на 4 ядрах, и вы будете использовать процессор на 100% вместо 25%.

Но при реальной нагрузке у вас будет несколько параллельных запросов. И ваш код попытается выполнить 4 параллельных запроса в 16 потоков на тех же 4 ядрах.

Гораздо эффективнее было бы не распараллеливать их, а выполнять "как есть" - т.к. они все равно загрузят процессор на 100%, и вместо улучшения времени ответа вы получите ухудшение - из-за расходов на синхронизацию и на переключение между потоками.

Comment: Превосходный ответ, благодарю. Уточню: "код все так же использует поток из пула - только отпускает текущий поток, и ждет выделения нового. а это может произойти не мгновенно.". Т.е. в ASP.NET Task.Run() не порождает новые потоки а ВСЕГДА берет имеющиеся из пула потоков?

Comment: @nikita да, `Task.Run` всегда берет поток из пула - [Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx). Если в пуле потока нет - то будет создано новый, но этим управляет сам пул, а не Task. Таск на потоке не из пула можно запустить вызовом [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321562(v=vs.110).aspx) с [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Все таки не совсем понятно: 
var result = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(); 
По Вашим словам выполняется действительно асинхронно. Но поток то все равно кто-то должен создать и ждать в нем завершения асинхронной задачи. Если этот поток не в пуле IIS то где? Как работает данный механизм ?

Comment: @nikita зависит от конкретного метода. например, вся работа с сетью сводится внутри к `Socket.BeginSend/Receive`, который в свою очередь вызывает [`WSARecv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx) в [overlapped io mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx). Т.е. managed code получает callback из нативного по завершению операции. Т.е. где-то что-то ес-но ждет результата, но это делается родными средствами ядра/драйверов, а не на уровне пользовательского кода.

Comment: @nikita вообще `async`/`await` это в принципе просто обертка/замена для старых методов BeginSomething/EndSomething, которые есть в .net достаточно давно. Если посмотреть по коду .net, то чаще всего Task получается вызовом `TaskFactory.FromAsync` из BeginOp/EndOp. А в BeginOp обычно где-то глубоко закопан вызов overlapped io.